# Solving for $y$ from multiple $y$ terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If you were given a problem like, $y^3+7y=16x^2-3x+2$, where there are multiple terms with $y$ of different powers in them, how would you solve for $y$?

Also, are there many situations where you would want to do this, or is this a form of equation that you can work with more easily than the result (which is really long; I looked it up on Wolfram Alpha)?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case, you have a cubic and you can use something like the [*roots of the cubic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function)